# How to unit test private variables mocha chai for Typescript project?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, chai

After researching this I found the best response would be to test the private variables of an object against the prototype of the object. Effectively then inside the test creating a prototype and accessing the variables in that way. When I do this however, it seems that all variables are not null but are undefined. How am I able to test the private variables, so that they remain defined? For reference, this is what I'm doing now:

Class:

```
export class KafkaConsumer {
  private consumer: kafka.ConsumerGroup;

  constructor(private sendFlextronicsDeviceSettingsHandler: any, redisService: RedisService) {
    this.redisService = redisService;
    const options: ConsumerGroupOptions = {
      fromOffset: 'latest',
      groupId: process.env.CONSUMER_GROUP_ID + '-' + new Date().getTime().toString() || 'fc-ds-devicesettings',
      kafkaHost: process.env.KAFKA_HOST,
      outOfRangeOffset: 'earliest',
      protocol: ['roundrobin'],
      sessionTimeout: 15000
    };

    this.consumer = new kafka.ConsumerGroup(options, process.env.KAFKA_TOPIC);
    LoggingService.info(`KafkaConsumer - Constructor: Topic: ${process.env.KAFKA_TOPIC}`, null);
  }
```

Failing Test:

```
describe('KafkaConsumer Construction Test', () => {
    const kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer(sendFlextronicsDeviceSettingsHandler, new RedisService());
    const kafkaConsumerProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(kafkaConsumer);
    it('Checking KafkaConsumer Initialization', () => {
        expect(kafkaConsumerProto).to.not.be.null;
        expect(kafkaConsumerProto.consumer).to.not.be.null;
        expect(kafkaConsumerProto.consumer).to.not.be.undefined;
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you don't test private members. Testing the public interfaces is usually what you want.

Also marking a field as `private` doesn't change the implementation of your class at all. It only changes how typescript allows to access those fields.

```
class Foo {
    private bar: string = 'bar'
}

console.log(new Foo().bar) // Type error, but if ignored outputs 'bar' anyway
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=51#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ0PQA4CcCWAbmAC4Cm0ARmDgFzQTH4B2A5tALzQDkVOXqAX1Spg8JhHghSAOhDwWACiakA7nEQKAlNN6bUAen3QAKgE8s5UjhzwcAGkoBXYtDwAzVyya3SAE2jwzljOMDzUXNBgTKYqYKZAA)

---

But given that, if you look at the compiled javascript there's nothing on the prototype for these private fields at all.

```
// Compiled JS from above example class
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.bar = 'bar';
    }
}
```

So your approach won't work. But if you just need to silence typescript to force it to allow access to your private field, you can always use `// @ts-ignore`

```
// @ts-ignore
console.log(new Foo().bar)
// No error, outputs 'bar'
```

But I really wouldn't recommend you do that. You are ignoring typescripts errors here. You set up the field as private, so you shouldn't be allowed to access it, even in tests. Test the code that uses that field, not the field it self. This way you can refactor your internal implementation, renaming whatever private fields you see fit, and as long as the public interface hasn't changed and the right values are still returned by your public methods, then you won't even have to update your tests in the future.